# Within a Unity VR Game, can I open Unity's web browser to a webVR app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, aframe, webvr

Question in the title.
Kind of like VR-Inception.

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you make the second app specifically to plug into Unity's architecture, then I'd say: not yet.

The feature you're searching for is called WebVR link traversal [and is said to be enabled in the latest chromium](https://iswebvrready.org/faq). This will enable to reuse webvr context. At this point this requires user intervention to enable WebVR "fullscreen" in the other app.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a WebView plugin in the app, it could be. If you use Application.OpenUrl then it will leave the app to open the browser so no.